# SPSS equivalent of Python Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, spss

I was trying to Google above, but knowing absolutely nothing about SPSS I wasn't sure what search phrase I should be using.

From my initial search (tried using words: "Dictionary" and "Scripting Dictionary") it seems there is something called Data Dictionary in SPSS, but description suggest it is not the same as Python Dictionaries.

Would someone be kind enough just to confirm that SPSS has similar functionality and if yes, can you please suggest key words to be used in Google?

Many thanks
dce

Comment: The use of objects in Python compared to accessing data and variables in SPSS is so different I would say there is no equivalent. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Andy W - I was showing one of my collegues from work how fast Dictionaries are and suggested to her to research this apporach in SPSS (she does big pieces of program which sometimes takes hours to run). Was simply trying to be helpful :)

Comment: You would need to be more specific about what the program is doing to give any advice about either timing or the level of sophistication needed to convert one job to another. SPSS can call python, so you can have the best of both if need be.

Comment: If you read the [wikipedia article on data dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dictionary) I think you will understand that this is a totally different concept to Python dictionaries. Most statistical software has some data dictionary command which usually just lists the variables in the dataset you have open along with their labels, data types, and sometimes other information such as the number of missing values.

Comment: Andy / Stuart - thank you for your input, I thought this question might be a little bit too general. I will take into account what you said and speak to my friend. Many thanks - dce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Python dictionary is an in-memory hash table where lookup of individual elements requires fixed time, and there is no deterministic order.  SPSS data files are disk-based and sequential and are designed for fast, in-order access for arbitrarily large amounts of data.

So these are intended for quite different purposes, but there is nothing stopping you from using a Python dictionary within Statistics using the apis in the Python Essentials to complement what Statistics does with the casewise data.